# Linking Google Maps Api Target with Android 2.1 Target

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have developed two separate applications 1) android 2.1 that takes user input / registers , shared pref and stuff and 2) Google Maps GPS on target Google APIs 7 . 
Now, I would like to embed the second project in first . That is, after the user registers it will bring up Maps and suggestions and stuff. How can I use both the targets (Apis ) together in a single App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use the Google APIs 7 target as it will also include the 2.1 one. The only difference is that it provides the Google Maps API library.

If you want to join both project together you will have to do it manually. I mean, copy the sources and resouces of the first project and cppy them into the project that has Google APIs 7 as target and copy. Then fix manually what you have to fix.  In conclusion: in order to join them, you will have to do some stuff manually.

There's another option, though. You can export your the first project as an JAR library and then include it into the second project's built path. The problem with this is that you will not be able to modify the source code of the 'library' one.

Comment: what if I am deploying the project on Droid. I am confused, there are two separate projects, I want to integrate them as one , and run on android

Comment: it cannot be automatically... take a look of my answer again

Comment: so Cristian, I first build the Maps API , download it and then add as JAR and then how do I display the stuff in Project 1 which extends activity.

Comment: You just have to use the `startActivity` method to open other activities.